# Reading a text file with numeric columns of different lengths

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file, generated by a FORTRAN program, with the rather strange (and surely annoying) format:

```
3.4502    1.5959    0.2160    0.9423    0.1098    1.2463   -2.8673    0.8803
3.5724    1.8022    0.3423    1.0801    2.4177   -0.2012   -0.1142   -0.2061
2.6028    2.6395    0.2959    0.8280    2.0526   -0.0721   -1.1345    0.0110
2.5628    0.0000    0.0539    0.0000   -0.4520    1.3030   -3.0792    1.0428
1.1823    1.4084    0.2315    1.1359    1.5945    3.2098    1.6739    0.0713
0.0296    1.3689    0.0000    1.0425   -0.4525    1.3043   -2.9785    1.0428
2.4825    1.6460    0.2573    2.4801    3.4533    1.5960    0.3609    0.9574
2.2358    0.8858    0.1344    0.5376    3.1102   -0.8025    0.1282   -0.8398
0.0000    1.4078    1.5464    1.0526    3.9754    3.7823    0.3376    0.1303
                                        3.3068    2.5148    0.2390   -0.3816
                                       -0.4672    1.3604    2.0157    1.0405
                                        4.4009    2.9969    0.8777    3.6270
                                        3.0271    4.1610    0.2094    3.0105
                                       -0.4889    1.3888    3.1442    1.0423
                                        6.0767    1.7731    0.6439    2.3744
                                        5.9313    1.3423    0.2204    1.0397
                                        4.4335    2.9075   -0.0328   -0.4526
                                        4.8670    2.6906    0.1088    0.0275
                                        2.5303    3.3157   -0.2649    0.9895
                                        4.3957    3.4142    0.3900    0.4282
                                        3.3185    1.4058    0.2024    3.3997
                                        0.9097    1.3423    0.2388    1.1809
                                        1.3302    1.6167    0.2009    1.0491
                                        2.4382   -0.1739    0.4722    3.5331
                                        1.8617    1.4082    0.2140    0.6741
```

I want to read separately the first four and the last four columns, storing them into Numpy arrays. Using numpy.genfromtxt, I easily got the data from first four columns:

```
object_scores = numpy.genfromtxt("results.out", usecols=(0,1,2,3), max_rows=9)
```

But when attempting to do the same for the other four columns

```
descriptor_scores = numpy.genfromtxt("results.out", usecols=(4,5,6,7), max_rows=25)
```

I got a long list of error messages, that seem to be related to the missing cells in the first four columns.

```
 ValueError: Some errors were detected !
     Line #10 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #11 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #12 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #13 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #14 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #15 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #16 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #17 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #18 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #19 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #20 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #21 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #22 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #23 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #24 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
     Line #25 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
```

Any hints or suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried passing `\t` as the `delimiter=` parameter?

Comment: you're getting an error message reading in the complete columns without missing rows versus the other?  have you tried using the skip_footer argument in place of max_rows

Comment: How big is the file, can you do it in a text editor that has *column* editing features before you try to use it??

Comment: `delimiter` can be a list of column widths.  It appears with that you could read all rows in`genfromtxt`, getting `nan` for the missing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unluckily the columns don't seem to have the same width (10 for the first four fields, then 11). If it is the case, the `delimiter=` option of `numpy.genfromtxt` could help you.

Here is an alternate solution to read the 4 fields starting at column 37:

```
descriptor_scores = numpy.genfromtxt([s[37:] for s in open("results.out")], usecols=(0,1,2,3), max_rows=25)
```

Comment: This worked! I had just to adjust the length of the string in the list comprehension from 37 to 41 and it worked fine. Thanks to you and all the others who boldly helped me to to tackle this annoying problem!

Answer (score 0):

If the file's format is always the same, this will do:

```
import numpy as np

def squash(obj):
    return [[float(element) for element in column if element.strip() != ''] for column in obj]

with open('results.out') as f:
    data = f.read()

lines = data.split('\n')

number_width = 6
number_spacing = 4

result = squash(zip(*[[line[i:i + number_width] for i in range(0, len(line), number_width + number_spacing)]
                      for line in lines]))

first_four_cols = np.array(result[0:4]).T
last_four_cols = np.array(result[4:]).T
```

Comment: Although an elegant solution, this didn't work. It returns both arrays empty.

Comment: That's strange; it works for me. Is my assumption that the file's format is always as you showed it in the question invalid?

Alternatively, is the filename correct?

Comment: Surely the filename is not the problem, as I would get an error even before reaching the call to the squash function. In fact, data seems to be read correctly, and lines is also filled right. The problem seems to be in the squash function, which is returning an empty list.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it since it worked for me with the data you gave in the question. Nevertheless, since you solved the problem, I guess it's all good!

Answer (score 0):

With a copy-n-paste to file

```
In [85]: data = np.genfromtxt('stack54544789.py', delimiter=[10]*8)
In [86]: data
Out[86]: 
array([[3.4502, 1.5959, 0.216 , 0.9423, 0.1098,    nan, 2.8673, 0.8803],
       [3.5724, 1.8022, 0.3423, 1.0801,    nan,    nan,    nan, 0.2061],
       [2.6028, 2.6395, 0.2959, 0.828 ,    nan,    nan, 1.1345, 0.011 ],
       [2.5628, 0.    , 0.0539,    nan, 0.452 ,    nan, 3.0792, 1.0428],
       [1.1823, 1.4084, 0.2315, 1.1359, 1.5945, 3.2098, 1.6739, 0.0713],
       ...
       [   nan,    nan,    nan,    nan, 1.3302, 1.6167, 0.2009, 1.0491],
       [   nan,    nan,    nan,    nan,    nan, 0.1739, 0.4722, 3.5331],
       [   nan,    nan,    nan,    nan, 1.8617, 1.4082, 0.214 , 0.6741],
       [   nan,    nan,    nan,    nan,    nan,    nan,    nan,    nan]])
```

That almost looks right; I think the extra `nan` come from negative signs that are misplaced.

```
In [87]: data = np.genfromtxt('stack54544789.py', delimiter=[9]+[10]*7)
In [88]: data
Out[88]: 
array([[ 3.4502,  1.5959,  0.216 ,  0.9423,  0.1098,  1.2463, -2.8673,
         0.8803],
       [ 3.5724,  1.8022,  0.3423,  1.0801,  2.4177, -0.2012, -0.1142,
        -0.2061],
       [ 2.6028,  2.6395,  0.2959,  0.828 ,  2.0526, -0.0721, -1.1345,
         0.011 ],
       [ 2.5628,  0.    ,  0.0539,  0.    , -0.452 ,  1.303 , -3.0792,
         1.0428],
       ...
       [    nan,     nan,     nan,     nan,  2.4382, -0.1739,  0.4722,
         3.5331],
       [    nan,     nan,     nan,     nan,  1.8617,  1.4082,  0.214 ,
         0.6741],
       [    nan,     nan,     nan,     nan,     nan,     nan,     nan,
            nan]])
```

Comment: This solution didn't work because it reads the data points columnwise and don't return the data in two separate arrays, one containing the first four columns and the other containing the last four.

Comment: It's easy to slice off the two parts from `data`,  `data[:x, :y]` etc

Answer (score 0):

Although it's certainly different from delimited formats like `.csv` (and thus may be annoying to some), Fortran and similar languages often use fixed width formats like this example. This is because they perform very well for larger files and they often directly match how the data is represented in memory, which makes it easier to code for in those languages.

I'm not sure your example contains the full data (StackOverflow may be getting rid of some whitespace for you). But I expect that, when you read the file directly, each column will be exactly 10 characters wide and you could read it like this:

```
def convert(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None


data = []
size = 10
with open('input.data', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # process line, minus the EOL (len(line)-1)
        data.append([convert(line[0+i:size+i]) for i in range(0, len(line)-1, size)])
```

Others have noticed that the width of the columns appears to vary, but I think this is just an artifact of you copying the data into your question - it seems highly likely that the fields are actually all the same width in the source data file.

Comment: This solution didn't work because it reads the data points columnwise and don't return the data in two separate arrays (or lists), one containing the first four columns and the other containing the last four.